# Sync 2 remote GIT repositories

Tags: git

I have one repository repo1 which is synced with remote1. I have 300 commits on it till date.

I created another repository repo2 on remote2 and has 4 commits till date. These are completely different commits.

I want to use repo1 and push changes to both remote1 and remote2. How can I do that?

When I push to remote2, it should overwrite all the commits from remote1.

Comment: you will need to do `git push remote1 master` and `git push remote2 master`, however you might get an error doing so since histories may be not related. In order to push in this case just add `-f` to your `git push` like so `git push -f remote1 master`

Comment: Do you mean git push -f remote2 master? What does -f do?

Comment: @dang `-f` is shorthand for `--force`, which does the same thing

Comment: It can cause the remote repository to lose commits; please be careful.

Comment: @EmL agree with you on this one, thankfully there are ways to get information back using `git reflog` and friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besically run

```
git push remote1 master
git push remote2 master
```

signature

> `git push <remote repository> <branch to push>`

if you run into an error due to histories being different, you can force push using following alternation

```
git push -f remote1 master
git push -f remote2 master
```

Note: `-f` is for force

Comment: I just did git push -f remote2 master, it doesn't overwrite commits on remote2.

Comment: @dang please either edit your question or make a new one. Your original post doesn't reflect a requirement to overwrite any of the commits. The above solution will allow you to push to both remotes you've specified in your OP.

Comment: added clarification in the question.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do here is just do an interactive rebase. Simply `pull` from your `remote2`. Run `git rebase -i` and place the commits you want to be on top at the start. In a long term, I would recommend to work on the strategy